# How to change a users password in Linux using C#

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, .net-6.0

Following scenario:

- I do have sudo permissions
- I know the old and new password of a user

Now I want to write a C# .NET 6 application which can change the password of the user.
In Linux I would just call

```
sudo passwd username
```

My first idea was to create a new process, redirect the stdin and write the password there.
Another option would be to create a bash script and call it from C# (also using a new process).

However, both seem a little bit hacky to me. Is there any option to change the password in-process in C#?

Comment: Use SSH.  The linux machine would need to enable SSH (or use Telnet).  See : https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET?force_isolation=true

Comment: I don't get it - why use SSH? My program runs on the same machine where I want to change the password of a user. There is no remote access needed.

Comment: Sorry.  Most people when they ask this question is doing it by a remote connection.  You can do it through a Process class which is equivalent to a shell command.   See : https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/10/29/the-net-process-class-on-linux?force_isolation=true#filename_resolution

Comment: Yes this was my first intention as already written in the main post. However I'm asking if theres a better, in-procces way to do it like hashing it and writing it to a file or something like that, e.g the shadow file, but Im not a Linux pro so dont know if this is doable or a good way to do

Comment: For the new password to work, it must use the algorithm that the login code uses which is written in c++.  You can write the code in c++ and then call the c++ from c#.

Comment: Wouldn't writing directly to the shadow file be more of a hack than just spawning a new process? Executing programs in child processes is the natural way of doing things in Linux. From the root `init` process down to the shell process in which commands launch programs in child processes too.

Comment: Using `/usr/sbin/chpasswd` might be easiest solution.

Comment: I looked at the option of modifying the shadow file directly, however the issue for me was I did not know how to get the salt for the system, that is used in the hashing process, if someone know hows to do that, I have the code for editing the shadow file directly with csharp already written.

The solution I have posted below I think is the best, it can be used local, as part of a ssh call, remotely via snmp or any protocol you want, you can just change it to a method within any code.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should work properly if you already have the linux shell script.

```
   if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux)){    
        var ShellScriptPath =  $"-c '{ShellScriptPath } &>> {OutputTextFilePath}'";
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(ShellScriptPath);
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
           CreateNoWindow = true,
           RedirectStandardOutput = true,
           RedirectStandardError = true,
           UseShellExecute = false,
           FileName = "/bin/bash",
           WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
           Arguments = fileInfo.FullName,
           WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectoryPath,
        };
        
        using Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();
        process.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Program.cs

```
class PasswordChanger
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    string password = args[1];
    string user = args[0];
    Console.WriteLine(ShellHelper.Bash($"echo -e \"{password}\n{password}\n\" | sudo passwd {user}"));
  }
}
```

LinuxHelper.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace LinuxHelper
{
  public static class ShellHelper
  {
    public static string Bash(string cmd)
    {
      string escapedArgs = cmd.Replace("\"", "\\\"");

      Process process = new Process()
      {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
          FileName = "/bin/bash",
          Arguments = $"-c \"{escapedArgs}\"",
          RedirectStandardOutput = true,
          UseShellExecute = false,
          CreateNoWindow = true,
        }
      };

      process.Start();
      string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
      process.WaitForExit();

      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

The above code works, takes two args first is the username , second is the password.  I have separated the solution into two files because the LinuxHelper/Shellhelper can be used for any shell command you need to call.  The main function/method can also be easily modified to be a standard method in any project.  If you do change the Main method to be a method inside a class, I suggest you change (string[] args) to (string user, string password) then you can remove the string declarations inside the method.